# Class 'Collective\Html\Facades\FormFacade' not found (View:)

Tags: php, laravel

i try implement Laravel Collective in Laravel 5.4. 
I updated Laravel Collective by

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

and configured config/app.php like this:

```
'providers' => [
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
'aliases' => [
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class
```

and when i try to make form like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'videos', 'class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}
    code..
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

in web browser Laravel give me error:

```
Class 'Collective\Html\Facades\FormFacade' not found (View: C:\kurs_laravel\resources\views\videos\create.blade.php)
```

and

```
Class 'Collective\Html\Facades\FormFacade' not found
```

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

Try this console command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

First clear your cache of the app,

`php artisan cache:clear`

then

`composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the following command:

```
composer update
```

In case it does not work, try to follow this step by step guide in laravel collective website:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html

I hope it helps !